# Can you take the form of a swarm with the polymorph spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, swarm

The [Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell says:

> The new form can be any beast whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target's

[Swarm of insects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/swarm-of-insects-beetles) says:

> Medium swarm of Tiny beasts

Can a wizard choose the form of a swarm with Polymorph, considering that even though its made up of many creatures it is treated as a single creature with one attack?

Comment: Related on [Can a druid wildshape into a swarm?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45991/can-a-druid-wild-shape-into-a-swarm-or-giant)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No.

Polymorph says:

> The new form can be **any beast** whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target's

It says "Any *beast*", not "Any creature". While swarms are indeed treated as single creatures for the purpose of the rules, they are defined as "swarms of tiny beasts", not as a "single beast", and thus not a valid form for Polymorph.

Check the answers on [this question about Wild Shape and Swarms](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45991/can-a-druid-wild-shape-into-a-swarm-or-giant?noredirect=1&lq=1) to see a similar conclusion for a very similar effect.

Comment: Agreed. You can polymorph to one of the swarm, such as one rat, but not a swarm of rats. Fortunately, we don't have any beasts that are considered one entity with multiple bodies (such as some hive minds in other fictional worlds)

Comment: Related on [how many creatures do you need to make a swarm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/181837/62294).